# What is meant by a "linear hyperplane" (and, therefore, a "nonlinear hyperplane")?

Tags: geometry

I am currently studying the textbook *Neural Networks and Deep Learning* by Charu C. Aggarwal. In chapter **1.2.1 Single Computational Layer: The Perceptron**, the author says the following:

> The type of model proposed in the perceptron is a *linear model*, in which the equation $\overline{W} \cdot \overline{X} = 0$ defines a linear hyperplane. Here, $\overline{W} = (w_1 \dots w_d)$ is a $d$-dimensional vector that is normal to the hyperplane. Furthermore, the value of $\overline{W} \cdot \overline{X}$ is positive for values of $\overline{X}$ on one side of the hyperplane, and it is negative for values of $\overline{X}$ on the other side.

I know what a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) is, but I don't understand what is meant by a "linear hyperplane" here. What is a "linear hyperplane", and, in that case, what would a "nonlinear hyperplane" be? I could not find information on this "linear" distinction.

Comment: Linear hyperplane means hyperplane.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Ok, thanks. In that case, what would a "nonlinear hyperplane" be?

Comment: Well, I think its not existing.

Comment: @Wuestenfux So you're saying that the "linear" vs "nonlinear" hyperplane distinction is nonsense?

Comment: I think it distinguishes between the linear and *affine* hyperplanes which are translations of linear hyperplanes.

Comment: @Berci If an affine hyperplane is defined as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane#Affine_hyperplanes , then what is the "linear" hyperplane that you're describing?

Comment: Linear hyperplane is an affine hyperplane which contains the origin.

Comment: @Berci oh, ok, I see what you mean.